# Wie sagt man " What to wear? " auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar

Man kann es vielleicht so sagen?

> Was soll ich anziehen?

Das ist aber mehr: *"What should I wear?"*

Geht es irgendwie ohne "soll" ? So etwas wie:

> Was anziehen?

Comment: „Geht“ denn “What to wear?” im Englischen? Sicher ist es verständlich, das ist „Was tragen?“ auch.

Answer (score 3):

> Was ziehe ich nur an?

Aber das drückt eher weibliche Verzweiflung vor dem Kleiderschrank aus :-)

Comment: "Was soll ich anziehen?" aber auch. Oder die männliche Frage, um die Verzweiflung der Frau über die Entscheidung schonmal vorwegzunehmen...

Comment: @PMF oder nur weiter zu verstärken. --> *"Was sollen* **wir** *anziehen?"*

Comment: @PMF *Was soll ich anziehen* kann ein Mann aber auf Fragen - wir wissen es einfach nicht. *Schatz, wir gehen in die Oper* => *Was soll ich anziehen?* ist doch da die natürliche Antwort des Mannes, oder nicht? Das verzweifelte *Was ziehe ich nur an?* kennt der Mann nicht - die logische Antwort lautet: *Das was oben liegt.*.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Genau das meinte ich. Wenn er nämlich einfach das nimmt, was zuoberst ist, dann gibt es bekannterweise dann ein "Diese Socken passen doch nicht!".

Answer (score 3):

Die englische Manier des Satztyps What to wear? mit Auslassung von shall I/should I ist im Deutschen nicht üblich. Gelegentlich kann man so was wohl finden, Aber Fragewort + to-Infinitiv ist eine typisch englische Satzstruktur. Englisch neigt viel mehr zu Auslassungen als das Deutsche.

Comment: In "what to wear" is nichts ausgelassen, schon gar kein "shall/should I" – das sind beides Modalverben, somit wäre in dem Satz kein "to" vorhanden. Vielmehr ist es einfach eine eigene Fragestruktur, Fragewort + Infinitiv, wie Du selbst anmerkst, *die es auch im Deutschen gibt*, dort allerdings ohne den Partikel *zu*: [Was tun?](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Was_tun%3F) Was anziehen? Wie weiterleben? Wohin fahren? Wozu anhalten? Warum nachdenken?

Comment: Sie meinen wohl, solche Konstruktionen fallen vom Himmel. Nein, sie werden erfunden. Und keiner beginnt wohl mit Fragewort + to-Infinitiv. Solche Sachen leiten sich von klaren, längeren Konstruktionen ab wie What am I expected to do. Erst wenn solche Formeln geläufig sind und häufig gebraucht werden, werden sie gekürzt und jeder versteht sie, weil eben die vollständige Formel zur Genüge bekannt ist. - Sie haben recht, ich hätte sagen sollen: Hier fehlt so was wie "expected to do" und nicht "shall/should", weil in der Konstruktion ein to-Infinitiv folgt. Das habe ich in der Eile übersehen.

Answer (score 2):

Ich denke, das englische "What to wear" drückt einen Allgemeinbezug des Satzes bzw. der Frage aus, den man bspw. auch aus den Überschriften in den Magazinen kennt ("Helloween, what to wear"). Im Deutschen kommt man dem gleichen Effekt sehr nahe, wenn man die neutrale Form "man" verwendet: "Was zieht man an?" In dieser Form vermeidet man unnötigen Selbstbezug ("Was soll ich anziehen?") und bleibt trotzdem flexibel (man kann den Satz auch nachdenklich vor dem Kleiderschrank über sich selbst sagen).

Answer (score 1):

Die beste Form ist wohl `Was soll/kann ich anziehen?`

Wobei inzwischen die oben genannten Formen auch korrekt werden.

Answer (score 0):

RegDwight has got it right, I think.

> Was anziehen?

or

> Was nur anziehen?

or

> Ach! -- was anziehen?

is the closest you'll hear in German. Certainly not something you'll find written down that often, but it's definitely used in speech.

Answer (score 0):

Also possible:

> Was kann/soll/sollte ich tragen?

That is used in a more general context, when not referring to a definite occasion like

> Was sollte man auf einer Konferenz tragen?

Concerning your example

> Was anziehen?

it is not correct and even probably almost never used, even though comprehensible (as lots of grammatically incorrect expressions are).